# How to upload and download file in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I want to upload and download file in hadoop. and want to store file in server or multi-node cluster.

Answer (score 5):

for putting files on hadoop use

```
 hadoop fs -put /<local machime path> /<hdfs path>
```

and to get files from hadoop use

```
 hadoop fs -get /<hdfs path> /<local machime path>
```

for more information see [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)

Comment: Provided link is broken. Nice example why it is recommended to post at least a tl;dr version of the link.

Comment: @Dror link is updated now thanks for the feedback

Comment: This is the same link as in the answer, but linked to "current" instead of a specific version "r2.7.0":   http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Answer (score 1):

To copy from local to hdfs, use this command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /temporaryfile.txt hdfs://DFCMSUSEHDSL03.pbi.global.pvt/sunil/temporaryfile.txt
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /temporaryfile.txt hdfs://DFCMSUSEHDSL03.pbi.global.pvt:8020/sunil/temporaryfile.txt
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -put /temporaryfile.txt /sunil/temporaryfile.txt
```